How to Integrate Raspbian OS Sensor Data with Mobius for Front-End Management?
We’re working on a project where a Raspbian OS device collects temperature and humidity data, sends it to a MySQL database, and we plan to manage this data via the Mobius IoT platform's front-end.
Currently, we’ve successfully sent the data to the database but we’re having trouble linking and managing this data through Mobius.
Our setup includes:
Raspbian OS sending data via Python.
Mobius installed locally on our server.
MySQL database storing sensor data.
How can we link the MySQL database with Mobius so that the front-end reflects the real-time sensor data?
We got this error:
AE Creation Failed: 400,
{"m2m:dbg":"BAD REQUEST: X-M2M-RI is none"}
Container Creation Failed: 400,
{"m2m:dbg":"BAD REQUEST: X-M2M-RI is none"}
Data Transmission Failed: 400,
{"m2m:dbg":"BAD REQUEST: X-M2M-RI is none"}

import requests
import json

# Mobius server info
BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:7579/Mobius"
HEADERS = {
    "X-M2M-Origin": "SOrigin",  # Mobius basic Origin
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

def create_ae(ae_name):
    """Application Entity (AE) creation in Mobius"""
    url = BASE_URL
    payload = {
        "m2m:ae": {
            "rn": ae_name,
            "api": "0.2.481.2.0001.001.000111",
            "rr": True,
            "poa": ["http://203.254.173.104:9727"]
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers={**HEADERS, "ty": "2"}, json=payload)
    if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
        print(f"AE creation success: {ae_name}")
    else:
        print(f"AE creation failed: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

def create_container(ae_name, container_name):
    """Container Creation in Mobius"""
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/{ae_name}"
    payload = {
        "m2m:cnt": {
            "rn": container_name
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers={**HEADERS, "ty": "3"}, json=payload)
    if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
        print(f"Container creation success: {container_name}")
    else:
        print(f"Container creation failed: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

def send_data(ae_name, container_name, data):
    """(ContentInstance) transmission in Mobius"""
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/{ae_name}/{container_name}"
    payload = {
        "m2m:cin": {
            "con": data  # send data 
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers={**HEADERS, "ty": "4"}, json=payload)
    if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
        print(f"data transmission success: {data}")
    else:
        print(f"data transmission failed: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

# example
if __name__ == "__main__":
    AE_NAME = "myApp"
    CONTAINER_NAME = "myContainer"
    DATA = "Hello, Mobius from Python!"

    # Step 1: AE creation
    create_ae(AE_NAME)

    # Step 2: Container creation
    create_container(AE_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME)

    # Step 3: data transmission
    send_data(AE_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME, DATA)


